# Collection group queries getting denied by firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

there's users, projects as top level collections, and tasks as a subcollection of projects
Below is security rules and i am having troubles allowing collection group queries on tasks. doesnt seem to work even if i remove the check for createdBy, when i run the simulator for a task resource, my rules works

```
match /projects/{projectID} {
  allow read, delete, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}

match /users/{userID} {
    allow read, delete, update: if request.auth.uid == userID;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}

match /projects/{projectID}/tasks/{taskID} {
  allow read, delete, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

here is my collectiongroup query

```
_firestore
    .collectionGroup('tasks')
    .where('dueDate', isEqualTo: DateTimeHelper.today)
    .where('createdBy', isEqualTo: user.id)
    .snapshots()
    .map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) {
          String projectId = doc.reference.parent().parent().documentID;
          String taskId = doc.documentID;
          return Task.fromDocument(doc, taskId, projectId);
        }).toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

None of your rules apply to collection group queries.  You should review the [documentation on rules for collection groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules).  From that page:

> In your security rules, you must explicitly allow collection group
>   queries by writing a rule for the collection group:
>
> 1. Make sure rules_version = '2'; is the first line of your ruleset. Collection group queries require the new recursive wildcard {name=**}
>      behavior of security rules version 2.
> 2. Write a rule for you collection group using match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}.

So your rule will look more like this:

```
rules_version = '2';  // at the very top of your rules

match /{path=**}/tasks/{taskID} {
  allow read, delete, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Comment: can you use the "taskID" variable to compare against something in security rules? Every time I try it errors out...i.e. taskID == resource.data.oldTaskID

Comment: @Leon It looks like we can't. I got the same behavior as you, when I try to use `taskID` is errors out